# SendGrid Random HTML Comment Response

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

Have been trying to create a campaign with SendGrid API. Adding lists, recipients, and recipients to lists all works fine. However, as soon as I try to add a new campaign my curl response is:

`<!-- This is a random-length HTML comment: jbxzwrreejuenlcislnnrtqpepguufquskweywdclekzbirxeqwozopyiewqhjumbhfwyepoosmzwyazpdzexczablujrbjiixmmmqjsashcfuwhguidzmnlqwpkmqkyqiuwbrdbiikvyyfkdxzfkcfvhsiqhpwowvtgvydjfabodxkdoycmhxhwhrqznppcaxevndlmftpomkoivcbkeonofgabbwalstlrajpptuhfdananzdgzlnavbinpxyzrgknkrqhyywwdnyhvgmwkvrcvheadfgdqvfviqdnrniqzfijxchyecjyzleznlwbfdlfbuwrbzlkaeftbhsiyoluymrzohgqxesvxxiadcpucmufdhcoenyeoagnssktmphhaximhfegozmayralqxdbbjfcoxxgeoqjsnbgyejalqmmpesmepqnbwykjaaorvljcxttkasnqxbkvrsshwkzywazfltmiyqdzugoezoaeynbkfsldmliqyiujnnriwgzendfgllnhyhxisimqojpncarhhhcyfxecwentpymluxvakpffuednakvxtplgclyjgprpyvwabkqldocwehynpucpgjukycrbsflglqljjitquqxnghesizdofkdvnzmxdrfopjqtvqvzffndalnaupeclmldvgoabignoeccpkbemyjyjeumyxzefrysrbtwpbdrhnkomvlnsrwctxwzioafmmovkybzpanychdfuvxovsnkuxchzmnuogngdcnuvaxuaejfwh -->`

Which isn't even JSON. It worked earlier, and on previous days, but all of a sudden the API responses are making no sense.

Comment: You've forgotten to add your curl response

Comment: no just new to posting on SO, forgot the backticks. updated though.